# issues with flexbox and screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have two questions that I'm hoping someone can provide some guidance on.  First, I have a row of font awesome icons that I'm formatting using flexbox.  When the screen size shrinks, I want to transform the flexbox so that the icons are vertical instead of squished horizontally. I've tried different things with transform, but can't seem to get it to work properly:

Normal width:
[image]

When screen size shrinks:
[image]

Additionally, I would like to add some texts underneath each icon in order to notify the user on what they're clicking on.  What do I have to add to my code in order for those to align properly?

Here is my current code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper i {
  color: $overdue;
  border: 3px solid $overdue;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 18px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.wrapper i:hover {
  background: $overdue;
  color: $color-lightest;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 $overdue;
  -webkit-animation: rubberBand 1s;
  animation: rubberBand 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-building fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-users fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-university fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `flex-direction: column` in order to turn your horizontal flexbox into a vertical one.

```
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

And, regarding putting some text, if I understood right, you should do this:

> ```
> <div class="wrapper">
>   <div>
>     <i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
>     <h3>Description</h3>
>   </div>
>   <div>
>     <i class="fa fa-building fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
>     <h3>Description</h3>
>   </div>
>   <div>
>     <i class="fa fa-users fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
>     <h3>Description</h3>
>   </div>
>   <div>
>     <i class="fa fa-university fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
>     <h3>Description</h3>
>   </div>
>   <div>
>     <i class="fa fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
>     <h3>Description</h3>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

:)

Comment: Thanks Gabriel! i had to mess around with your css a bit, but this definitely helped a ton!